# Return array of objects matching object.date and summing object.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Return array of objects matching object.date and summing object.value

[[image: object[1]]

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum values grouped by date, you could use an intermediary object as map, and then sum each date:

```js
function sumValuesGroupByDate(input) {
  var dates = {};
  input.forEach(dv => dates[dv.date] = ((dates[dv.date] || 0) + dv.value));
  return Object.keys(dates).map(date => ({date, value: dates[date]}));
}

var input = [
  {date: "2017-07-10", value: 1}, {date: "2017-07-11", value: 3},
  {date: "2017-07-10", value: 5}, {date: "2017-07-11", value: 7}
];
console.log(sumValuesGroupByDate(input));
```

And if you are into one-liners of raw ES6 JavaScript power, here it goes:

```js
function sumValuesGroupByDate(input) {
  return Object.entries(input.reduce((dvs, {date: d, value: v}) => ({...dvs, [d]: (dvs[d] || 0) + v}), {})).map(([date, value]) => ({date, value}));
}

var input = [
  {date: "2017-07-10", value: 1}, {date: "2017-07-11", value: 3},
  {date: "2017-07-10", value: 5}, {date: "2017-07-11", value: 7}
];
console.log(sumValuesGroupByDate(input));
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Return array of objects matching a date value:

```
const resultArray = array.filter(arrayItem => arrayItem.date === dateValue);
```

Return sum of values

```
const reducer = (summedValue, value) => summedValue + value;
const sum = array.reduce(reducer));
```